# Is there a webkit for the RPi?

Tags: display, web-interface

**Context:** I wrote some time ago a dashboard which displays text in text widgets placed on a fullscreen window (no user interaction, the content of the widgets changes when receiving signals). It is running on Raspbian, developed on Windows) and based on Qt (`PyQT4`)

It works fine but the displayed text is hardly configurable (specifically, it handles only a small subset of CSS)

I am now planning to change the display part so that it is entirely based on CSS and JavaScript (using AJAX).

**My question:** Since this is the only application running on the RPi (at lest from a GUI point of view) I would like to use `<something>` which would natively display the HTML/CSS/JS content, in read-only mode (that is there is no user interaction).

This is akin to a web browser in fullscreen mode, but without any "end user" web browser functionality, something which would handle the graphical aspects but be launched as a fullscreen application (the HTML/CSS/JS rendering part, basically). As I mentioned, today this is `PyQT4`, with a `root` windows launched in `.showFullScreen()` mode.

What direction should I be looking in, in a RPi context?

Note: the backend (and, today, frontend) is written in Python. Since the GUI will be completely AJAX based (all business logic is in the backend), I can go for anything which accepts HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: why not a browser instance in fullscreen mode?
I found this online
http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-boot-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-fullscreen-browser-kiosk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a **web browser in kiosk mode**.

The aptly named [**Minimal Kiosk Browser**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=40860) ("kweb" and "kweb3") is highly customizable , so don't forget to read the manual !

It is explicitly designed for "embedded" applications ,
so i guess it fits nicely.

Remove keyboard and mouse or check the manual whether an option to disable 
input exists (wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: I tried it but it unfortunately does not support [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I will look at chromium (not obvious to install with the current `testing`, or epiphany)

Comment: There is a difference between kweb and kweb3 so far i know , do neither work ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) which allows to build HTML/CSS/JS/(framework) application as executables.

The excellent framework [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) has this bult-in.